# Backbone.js - Give a strict order of view events handlers calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, view

I need somehow to make my `keydown` event to fire before `input` event ALWAYS.

```
class RowView extends Backbone.View
    events:
      'keydown .js-field' : 'onKeydown'
      'input .js-field' : 'onInput'
```

Is it possible to make it call these handlers in strict order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should *always* be called in that order given the event sequence in all browsers – keypress, keydown, input, keyup, etc. – but if you want to see and have more fine-grained control, you could attach the same callback to both events and then use `event.type` to see which one was called, and then delegate from there.

Comment: binding order doesn't matter (backbone rendering), they'll be fired as per the browser event sequence

Comment: @coding_idiot letters bind like ``1. input, 2. keydown`` and numbers as ``1. keydown, 2. input``

Comment: @Kosmetika go the event bus route then - use the same callback and inspect `event.type`.